Regex Guide: Getting a specific value from a text file using powershell/cmd
Im using powershell or cmd to open a text file and get a specific value or text inside.
Currently the output looks like this inside the text file:
Upload Hello.zip: 0 of 933 bytes complete

Upload Hello.zip: 933 of 933 bytes complete
{
  "scanId" : 11260434,
  "scanType" : "Static",
  "analysisStatusType" : "Pending",
  "applicationName" : "Test Application Jenkins",
  "releaseName" : "Release 4",
  "microserviceName" : "",
  "__action__" : "STARTED"
}

However, I only would like to get the value from the scan ID.
This is the command I use:
Select-String -Path C:\Folder\scanjson.txt ':\s*(?<digits>[0-9]+)'

But It would return the output like this:
C:\Folder\scanjson.txt:2:Upload Hello.zip: 0 of 933 bytes complete
C:\Folder\scanjson.txt:4:Upload Hello.zip: 933 of 933 bytes complete
C:\Folder\scanjson.txt:6:  "scanId" : 11260434,


Try "scanId"\s*:\s*(?<digits>[0-9]+)?


Since your text file is mostly JSON, it is better and more robust to remove the non-JSON preamble and use ConvertFrom-Json to parse the JSON into an object whose properties you can access to get the desired information:
# -> 11260434, i.e. a *number*, due to from-JSON parsing.
(
  (Get-Content -Raw C:\Folder\scanjson.txt) -replace '(?s)^.+(?=\{)' |
    ConvertFrom-Json
).scanId


Get-Content -Raw reads the file as a whole into a single, multiline string.

-replace '(?s)^.+(?=\{)' removes everything up to, but excluding, the first { character; the components of the regex are as follows:

(?s) is an inline option that makes . match newline characters too.
^ matches at the start of the string.
.+ matches any nonempty (+) run of characters (.); if your input file doesn't always have a preamble, use .* instead.
(?=\{) is a lookahead assertion that matches a { character without including it in the match.
By not specifying a substitution expression, the match is replaced with the empty string, i.e. effectively removed.


The resulting string is valid JSON that ConvertFrom-Json parses into [pscustomobject] instances, whose properties, such as .scanId, you can access.

Note that, unlike the strictly text-based regex-parsing, JSON supports a few data types, causing an unquoted token such as 11260434 to be parsed as a number.
An integer - such as in the case at hand - is parsed as type [int] (System.Int32) in Windows PowerShell vs. as [long] (System.Int64) in PowerShell (Core) 7.




As for what you tried:
Your regex was too permissive; use
"scanId"\s*:\s*(?<digits>[0-9]+) instead;[1] i.e.:
# -> '11260434', i.e. a *string*, due to regex parsing.
(
  Select-String -List -Path C:\Folder\scanjson.txt '"scanId"\s*:\s*(?<digits>[0-9]+)'
).Matches[0].Groups['digits'].Value

Note the need to drill down into the Select-String output object, which is of type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo], to get the capture-group value of interest.
-List ensures that matching stops after the first match.

Note: In cases where you expect multiple matches, you'd omit -List and pipe to a ForEach-Object call instead of using direct property access on the result (as shown above):
Select-String -Path C:\Folder\scanjson.txt '"scanId"\s*:\s*(?<digits>[0-9]+)'| 
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups['digits'].Value }



Due to using regex-based parsing, the result is a string, simply cast the entire expression to, e.g. [int] to get a number.

[1] For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see this regex101.com page. Note that regex101.com's .NET support is limited to C#, which may require tweaks to PowerShell regexes, such as not using '...' and escaping " chars. as ""; see this answer for guidance.

Thanks! The main comment/answer worked for me.
Aso for the one I tried, I was testing it on this website: https://regex101.com/r/IgaNue/1

Glad to hear it, @George; the Select-String solution should work too, though it returns a string (that you can easily cast to [int]). By contrast, the ConvertFrom-Json solution returns a number (of type [int] in Windows PowerShell vs.  [long] in PowerShell (Core) 7)

I was using this before:
Select-String -Path C:\Folder\scanjson.txt '"scanId":\s*(?<digits>[0-9]+)' -List | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups['digits'].Value }

@George: That works in principle, but the regex is broken; this works: Select-String -Path C:\Folder\scanjson.txt '"scanId"\s*:\s*(?<digits>[0-9]+)' -List | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups['digits'].Value }. Since only one result is expected, my solution makes do without a ForEach-Object call.

@George, re your regex101.com link: you had syntax errors, because the site requires C# syntax; please see the footnote I've just added, which has a link with a corrected attempt, and a link to an answer that explains how to generally test PowerShell regexes on regex101.com.

My bad, I can confirm that the Select-String method is also now working.  I could also try this command directly without having to save the data into a text file. thanks again!
